# GridControl Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I got **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** w
 I read it first to DataTable then

```
  gridControl2.DataSource = dataTable5;
```

I read .txt file to GridControl just fine.
I got the error After using :

```
gridView2.Columns["SomethingA"].Visible = false;
```

I don't think there is null values on the Columns since I took those values using a SQL Query and avoided null values.

**EDIT: Full code**

```
 char[] chrArray10 = new char[1];
        chrArray10[0] = '\t';
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("C:/Users/PC-ASQ/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1/bin/Debug/Mydll.dll");

        System.Resources.ResourceManager resourcemanager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources", assembly);


        var textList = resourcemanager.GetString("GISS").Split(chrArray10);
        string[] strArrays15 = resourcemanager.GetString("GISS").Split('\n');


        string[] strArrays16 = strArrays15[0].Split(chrArray10);
        DataTable dataTable5 = new DataTable();
        string[] strArrays17 = strArrays16;
        for (int s = 0; s < (int)strArrays17.Length; s++)
        {
            string str5 = strArrays17[s];
            dataTable5.Columns.Add(str5);
        }
        for (int t = 1; t < (int)strArrays15.Length; t++)
        {
            char[] chrArray11 = new char[1];
            chrArray11[0] = '\t';
            dataTable5.Rows.Add(strArrays15[t].Split(chrArray11));
        }


        gridControl2.DataSource = dataTable5;


       gridView2.Columns["ToolTip"].Visible = false;
       gridView2.Columns["Icons"].Visible = false;


        return;
```

Comment: The full exception stack trace would help here.

Comment: Also what platform are you on? Winform? ASP.NET? Is this the native gridcontrol or a 3rd party's?

Comment: WinForms ~~ GridControl from DevExpress Controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with this code,it's working fine.

```
 DataTable datatable5 = new DataTable();
 datatable5.Columns.Add("ToolTip");
 datatable5.Columns.Add("Icons");
 datatable5.Columns.Add("ID");
 datatable5.Columns.Add("Number");

 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     datatable5.Rows.Add(new object[] { String.Format("ToolTip{0}.", i),i,i,i});

  gridControl2.DataSource = dataTable5;

  gridView2.Columns["ToolTip"].Visible = false;
  gridView2.Columns["Icons"].Visible = false;
```

In your code : place a `breakpoint` and check how the `column names` are adding to `datatable`

```
 DataTable dataTable5 = new DataTable();
 string[] strArrays17 = strArrays16;
 for (int s = 0; s < (int)strArrays17.Length; s++)
 {
     string str5 = strArrays17[s];
     dataTable5.Columns.Add(str5);//check any extra space adding here
 }
 for (int t = 1; t < (int)strArrays15.Length; t++)
 {
     char[] chrArray11 = new char[1];
     chrArray11[0] = '\t';
     dataTable5.Rows.Add(strArrays15[t].Split(chrArray11));
 }
```

Comment: it's one Grid , GridControl of DevExpress is like that .
you have GridControl & GridView . 
and as I said .. I can hide one column .. but the second I cant :(

Comment: I know that's DevExpress GridControl,please check your question what you have named GridControl..?Can you please post the full code,so we can see how you are able to hide one column and not another one.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Does the "SomethingA" grid column even exists?</s>

You're saying there's no null values because you make sure your query doesn't result any, but that's irrelevant on how you reach to your visual grid column object. If the grid has no "SomethingA" column then regardless of the data your code will fail for sure.

(The above is irrelevant now that I know we're talking about the XtraGrid)

**UPDATE:**

Okay first, to retrieve a DevExpress's `GridView` column by field name, you must use the column collection's [`ColumnByFieldName`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumnCollection_ColumnByFieldNametopic) method:

```
gridView2.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("SomethingA").Visible = false;
```

Second, next time you ask a question, **be sure to include all the necessary details**. The fact that you are using a 3rd party grid, as you can see, changes everything. Not every grids out there are the same. I edited your post to add relevant tags. In the future, be sure to include them.

Third, when asked for an [exception stack trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it means that the error message alone isn't enough to properly diagnose the problem. The stack holds important information about the steps your code is taking. If you want help on an exception you are having it's best to provide that information.

Fourth and last, DevExpress have their own [support center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/). Your questions will likely be better answered there.

Comment: What do you mea,n exactly ? :x

Comment: The Grid Do have this Column .

Comment: @user3091970 Then your code cannot be crashing at the line you mention. Please add the full exception stacktrace and the actual line of code that fails.

Comment: The line of code that fails : gridView2.Columns["SomethingA"].Visible = false;

Comment: @user3091970 as I said: if *this* is the line that crashes then your "SomethingA" column simply doesn't exist. Either that or your actual `gridView2` variable is null. Please edit your original answer and post the full exception stacktrace. This will all become clear.

Comment: it's the only error that I get :x 
the weird thing is that I'am loading 4 Columns . split '\t' 
I want to hide the 2 Last , SomethingB I can hide it but not SomethingA

Comment: @user3091970 You understand what exception objects are, don't you?

Comment: @user3091970 I updated my answer again. See if it helps.

Comment: Always same error with Exception :

System.NullReference.Exception :  Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Line : 89 which is the one for hide